# How to make an internal hyperlink in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How to make an internal hyperlink in Sphinx documentation?
I am using:

```
:role:`target`
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Cross-referencing is done using a `ref`

```
:ref:`label-name`
```

You can provide your labels using:

```
.. _label-name:
```

See: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref

Roles are used to create custom interpreted text. See: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#role

Answer (score 4):

In somewhere the heading is,

```
.. _HeaderTag:

Header
------
```

Ref to above header (may not the same file)

```
:ref:`HeaderTag`

# or with custom text
:ref:`custom header<HeaderTag>`
```