# How to make an internal link to a heading in sphinx restructuredtext without creating arbitrary labels?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a document with many headings and sub-headings. Further into the text I want to link back to one of the headings. How can I do this without the redundancy of `:ref:` labels? The contents seems to pick up headers just fine. I was hoping for something like this: `` `#polled-data-retrieval`_ ``.

Comment: If you want to use backticks in an inline code block see [this meta SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138912/181221).

Comment: Most readers probably just want [this authoritative answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another-page) rather than any of the answers below. *This is why we mark duplicates, folks.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a cross-reference to a subheading or anchor in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another-page)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

reStructuredText supports [implicit hyperlink targets](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets). From the [reStructuredText quick reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets):

> Section titles, footnotes, and citations automatically generate hyperlink targets (the title text or footnote/citation label is used as the hyperlink name).

So the following text (lifted from the reStructuredText quick reference, spelling mistakes and all):

```
Titles are targets, too
=======================
Implict references, like `Titles are targets, too`_.
```

produces HTML similar to the following:

```
<strong><a name="title">Titles are targets, too</a></strong>

<p>Implict references, like <a href="#title">Titles are targets, too</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Using the headline text isn't a good choice. Headlines may change or might get corrected. There is now easy way to figure out who many and where links are broken after a change. You should use explicit linking with references (like LaTeX does since ages.)

Answer (score 31):

A small addition to the answer by Chris:

If you want to link to headings without using the exact name of that heading for the link, you can do it like this:

```
Titles are targets, too
=======================

See `here <#titles-are-targets-too>`_
```

This will render as:

```
<h1 id="titles-are-targets-too">Titles are targets, too</h1>

<p>See <a href="#titles-are-targets-too">here</a></p>
```

Comment: **This is the most general-purpose answer.** Most answers assume Sphinx, which is certainly fair enough for a question referencing Sphinx. Since Sphinx fails to apply to generic reStructuredText documents (e.g., `README.rst` in GitHub or GitLab repositories), however, answers assuming Sphinx-specific `:ref:` syntax fail to generalize. See also [this authoritative answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another-page).

Comment: @CecilCurry Unless you need the output to work in something that isn't a browser.

Answer (score 30):

**New, better answer for 2016!**

The [autosection extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosectionlabel.html) lets you do this easily, with real cross references.

```
=============
Some Document
=============


Internal Headline
=================
```

then, later...

```
===============
Some Other Doc
===============


A link-  :ref:`Internal Headline`
```

This extension is built-in, so all you need is to edit `conf.py`

```
extensions = [
    .
    . other
    . extensions
    . already
    . listed
    .
    'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel',
]
```

The only thing you have to be careful of is that now you can't duplicate internal headlines across the doc collection. (Worth it.)

Comment: Thank you. I kept thinking this was always enabled by default, couldn't figure out why some of my refs weren't working.

Comment: A minor addition: `:ref:\`Short link <Very long headline that clutters your text otherwise>\`` is possible as well

Comment: This option worked for me, thank you! However, it is not compatible with `sphinx_togglebutton`  extension. Do you have any suggestion on it or should I compose a new question about it?

Answer (score 11):

Using the headline text isn't a good choice. Headlines may change or might get corrected. There is now easy way to figure out who many and where links are broken after a change.

> Using ref is advised over standard reStructuredText links to sections (like `` `Section title`_ ``) because it works across files, when section headings are changed, will raise warnings if incorrect, and works for all builders that support cross-references.
>   Source: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref

Using the [`sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel` extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html) as proposed by [Adam Michael Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107431/3719459) is at least a more structured approach then using implicitly defined anchors as proposed by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704682/3719459).

---

You should use explicit linking with references and symbolic target names (like LaTeX does since ages.)

1. Use `.. _refname:` to create a target.
2. Use `` :ref:`refname` `` to reference the target.

If a target is followed by a headline, this headline will be used als link text.

Comment: Reading the first part of the answer I'm thinking "yeah, makes sense" but... when are the examples, *how* should one actually use it?