# How to create a link to a header in restructuredtext?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a document in restructuredtest like:

```
Header 1
========
```

and from some any other point (might be the same 'rst' file or a different one) I want to create a hyperlink to that header. So that when a user clicks on it, he gets to the page with the header `Header 1`

How to do that?

I tried to put the following line in the other document (according to [this documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html)):

```
see :ref:`Header 1`
```

but what I get is the following:

```
see Header 1
```

without any link...

I also tried to follow [this documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html):

What I put in to the `rst` file is the following

```
see `Header 1`_
```

and what I see is the following link:

```
see `Header 1`_
```

which does not look very nice ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first link was almost correct.  You need to add a label preceding the section header, separated by a blank line.  See [Inline markup, Cross-referencing arbitrary locations, using the `:ref:` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role).

In your case:

```
.. _header-1-label-name:

Header 1
========

Some text

Here is a section reference: :ref:`header-1-label-name`.

Here is a section reference with a title: :ref:`Header 1 with a title <header-1-label-name>`.
```

Comment: But I do not understand - why are all the documentations wrong? What do I miss there?

Comment: The documentation is correct. The example I wrote is derived from the documentation in the link I provided.

Comment: That means I found wrong or incorrect documentation? I have used the description from the two pages I included in my question. Did I do something wrong? Are these documents incorrect? Maybe outdated?

Comment: The documentation is current and correct. I copy-pasted the examples from http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations then edited it only slightly into a single example. What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704682) which claims that headers form implicit targets, meaning that ` `Header 1`_ `  _should_ work, too?

Comment: You are welcome to use [implicit hyperlink targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets), but that introduces ambiguity and potential errors. It is much preferred to use `ref` with explicit labels. From https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role, "Using ref is advised over standard reStructuredText links to sections (like `Section title`_) because it works across files, when section headings are changed, will raise warnings if incorrect, and works for all builders that support cross-references."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894064/2426064), the label you add (in this case `.. _header-1-label-name:`) is required to have a dash. So a simple `.. _label:` won't do. Took me a while to figure that out.