# Managing Sphinx toctrees combined with inline sections

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm trying to learn how I can manage a `toctree` element that is located in the same file as other content.

Suppose I have a thingamajig.rst chapter that looks like this:

```
Thingamajigs
============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   foo
   bar
   baz

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun
```

When I render it --- foo/bar/baz have their own .rst files --- it looks like this:

[image]

But if I move the `Overview` section *before* the toctree, then it pushes the toctree down into the Overview section:

```
Thingamajigs
============

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   foo
   bar
   baz
```

[image]

**Is there any way to have my toctree *after* the Overview section, but located under the Thingamajigs section?**

Alternatively, can I do something like this?

```
Thingamajigs
============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Overview          <-- refers to Overview section in same file
   foo
   bar
   baz

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section headings hierarchy is simply [the order as encountered](https://docutils.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections).  So your ==== underline sets the title ("H1") and ++++ underline sets the subtitle ("H2") for **this page only**.  Depending what layout you're after...

A. Maybe you wanted a "Table of contents" section as a sibling of the "Overview" section (both within "Thingamajigs" parent), so insert a new H2 section heading:

```
Thingamajigs
============

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun


Table of contents
+++++++++++++++++

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    foo
    bar
    baz
```

B. Or maybe you don't want "Overview" in the section headings hierarchy at all, so highlight it by a different means:

```
Thingamajigs
============

.. admonition:: Overview

    Thingamajigs are fun

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    foo
    bar
    baz
```

C. Or list the headings hierarchy within this page, separately from external pages:

```
.. contents:: In this page
    :local:

.. beware, that contents directive must appear before any heading hierarchy

Thingamajigs
============

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2
    :caption: In other pages
    
    foo
    bar
    baz
```

D. Or do exactly what your last example showed: move the "Overview" content out to a separate ReST document and include its name in the `toctree` directive body.

Comment: thanks, I'll try these suggestions and see if any of them feel right.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the "Overview" section to appear in the TOC but its contents to appear in the same page as the TOC. I guess that's what I can't figure out how to do. (I suspect you can't just add something in a toctree unless it's a separate file.)

Comment: *I suspect you can't just add something in a toctree unless it's a separate file*. That is true. A `toctree` entry is the name of a file.

Comment: AFAIK [contents](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) directive lists local (current document) hierarchy, [toctree](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) directive lists external documents, there isn't a hybrid.  You could fake a toctree by making a manual list of [references to section titles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704682/3627580), but it would be ugly.

Comment: Another kludge: move the "Overview" content out to a separate ReST document and include its name in the `toctree` directive body, then use `.. include:: overview.rst` [directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) so the overview is also visible beside the toctree

Comment: "A" is the cleanest; not quite what I wanted, but it looks like I can't get that without resorting to evil tricks and rewriting the doctree.

Answer (score 3):

The exact specification given in the question can be satisfied, but not without significant issues that require workarounds.

> Is there any way to have my toctree after the Overview section, but located under the Thingamajigs section?

By placing a toctree inside the `Overview` section your are placing all of that toctree's "Entries" (`.rst` files) inside that section and thus below that level in the section hierarchy.

> [However, a document must be consistent in its use of section titles: once a hierarchy of title styles is established, sections must use that hierarchy.](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections)

Pacing a toctree outside its pretended section will impact 1) "navigation", 2) "numbering" and 3) "depth".

**First step of the workaround:**

You *can* declare a toctree with the `:hidden:` option exactly where you want it -inside the `Thingamajigs` section- thus having 1), 2) and 3) working as intended. Sphinx will process the entries in the first toctree declaration, so afterwards the toctree declared inside `Overview` won't affect 1), 2) and 3) because the `.rst` entries were already processed.

The result:

[image: image1]

Corresponding `thingamajigs.rst`:

```
Thingamajigs
============

.. toctree::
    :hidden:

    foo
    bar
    baz

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun

.. toctree::

    foo
    bar
    baz
```

The above satisfies the problem exactly as it was specified in the question.

(Sphinx will issue warnings because the same `.rst` file was included in more than one toctree, but they aren't errors just warnings.)

**Second step of the workaround:**

However, now comes a surprise! If you go one level up, to the `.rst` containing the toctree that has `thingamajigs.rst` as an entry, you'll find the `:hidden:` toctree wasn't rendered, and instead the visible toctree is rendered "in place" (out of order):

The result:

[image: image2]

Corresponding `level_2_toctree.rst`:

```
***************
Level_2_toctree
***************

.. toctree::

    fill_tree1
    fill_tree2
    fill_tree3
    fill_tree4
    thingamajigs
```

Although 1), 2) and 3) are working (in terms of the toctrees retaining their functionality), this leaves us with a problem: fixing the rendering order in parent toctrees. The obvious solution is to repeat the original lower level toctree "as is" inside a bullet list and adding references targeting the sections:

The result:

[image: image3]

Corresponding `level_2_toctree.rst`:

```
***************
Level_2_toctree
***************

.. toctree::

    fill_tree1
    fill_tree2
    fill_tree3
    fill_tree4

.. toctree::
    :hidden:

    thingamajigs


- :ref:`5.5. Thingamajigs <target_thingamajigs>`


    .. toctree::

        foo
        bar
        baz

    - :ref:`5.5.4. Item Overview <target>`


.. toctree::

    foo2
    bar2
```

Notice you would have to add [hyperlink targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) to the original `thingamajigs.rst`.

```
.. _target_thingamajigs:

Thingamajigs
============

.. toctree::
    :hidden:

    foo
    bar
    baz

.. _target:

Overview
++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun

.. toctree::

    foo
    bar
    baz
```

**Third step of the workaround:**

But this has another problem, the HTML theme may have different CSS styles for bullet lists and toctrees, both are processed as different HTML elements (examine the source).

One solution would be to [wrap the block including the 2 delimiting references in a reST directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives) (a container) that allows for custom styling as to make the block "blend in" with the remaining toctree. However, you would have to propagate this customizing at every step of ascending the toctree chain.
This does provide a general solution as *"proof of concept"* for having a *"portable toctree"* placed out of context. The two main drawbacks are having to manually refactor the hyperlink numbering, and the overhead and expertise required to customizing the CSS.

**No more workarounds:**

Consider the [Sphinx `toctree` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5/markup/toctree.html#the-toc-tree) and the [reStructuredText `contents` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) are very different. While the whole point of the `toctree` is chaining `.rst` files together, the aim of the `contents` directive is providing a nice table of contents of the `.rst` file (or the section) it is in.

Try the useful `:backlinks:` option of the `contents` directive, by clicking back and forth between the [upper index](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#id55) and the corresponding [section](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) of its documentation.

"Ideally" the best way to avoid workarounds is using the right tool for the job at hand.

The third option that's a complement to the above two is using a [bullet list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists) made of [hyperlink targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets). It's flexible and allows to mix links both internal and external to the `.rst` file containing the bullet list. Plus it doesn't interfere with the automatisms of the `toctree` or the `contents` directives - which depend on sections. The second step of the workaround includes both of the bullet lists' essential elements.

> I'm trying to learn how I can manage a toctree element that is located in the same file as other content.

Looking at `toctree`s in the official Python documentation [one example](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), or [another example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) you see the ["Flat, Simple, Special cases..." from the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2) reflected. Most prominent documentations I've seen [chose simple toctree layouts](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html).

Without changing the specified presentation, the most efficient solution is using a bullet list of references to hyperlink targets inside `Overview` instead of the toctree.

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented about `toctree` and `contents`, so I won't repeat them.

You can do a hack with the `raw` directive.

```
Thingamajigs
============

.. raw:: html

    <h2><span class="section-number">1.1. </span>Overview<a class="headerlink" href="#overview" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h2>

.. Overview
.. ++++++++

Thingamajigs are fun

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    foo
    bar
    baz
```

To get the HTML that I used in the `raw` directive, I started with "Overview" and its underline to generate the HTML.  Next I copied it from the generated HTML and pasted it as you see above, indenting it under the `raw` directive.  Finally I commented out "Overview" and its underline.  You can season your raw HTML to taste.

Personally, however, I do not see the point of having both a title, immediately followed by an "Overview" or "Introduction" heading, immediately followed by the content of the overview or introduction.  I would remove the heading and simply display the desired content.  It's obvious what it is, so why does it need a heading?