# How link to a title in another document?

Tags: markup, restructuredtext

I would like to link from within document `A` to `Some Title` in document `B`.

- I know that I can do this within document `B` via `'Some Title'_`
- I know that I can reference document `B` from document `A` via `:doc:'B'`

Is there a way to combine both? (I tried combinations like `:doc:'B/Some Title'` but they did not work)

Note: the straight quote in the examples above should be a backtick but I do not know how to escape a backtick in the code mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestructuredText: Adding a cross-reference to a subheading or anchor in another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/restructuredtext-adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another)

Comment: Thanks - the referenced question indirectly answers mine: it looks like what I am trying to do is not possible (one can either link to title sections within one file, or to link to specific, hard-coded references in other files)