# reStructuredText in Sphinx: display number when referencing a section

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

To reference a section using reStructuredText in Sphinx, I can do:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19543591/1391441).

This results in the section being referenced **by title**, that is I get the line:

> It refers to the section itself, see *[Section to cross-reference](http://section-to-cross-reference)*.

(where *Section to cross-reference* links to the beginning of the corresponding section)

I'd like to get instead:

> It refers to the section itself, see *[2.1](http://section-to-cross-reference)*.

where *2.1* is the section's number.

Is there a way to accomplish this using reStructuredText in Sphinx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numsec` Sphinx extension does what you want. The source code is here: https://github.com/jterrace/sphinxtr/blob/master/extensions/numsec.py.

The extension is part of the "Sphinx Thesis Resource" package developed by Stack Overflow member [jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624900/jterrace). See https://github.com/jterrace/sphinxtr.

Comment: Thank you very much mzjn! The `numsec` extension worked perfectly and that package also has many other very interesting stuff.