# Sphinx cross reference not working

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

In my scipy-style docstring I have:

```
..., see :ref:`notes <filt_int_notes>`.

Other text.

.. _filt_int_notes:

Notes
-----
Some cool notes.
```

According to [Adding a cross-reference to a subheading or anchor in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/restructuredtext-adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another) and 
http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref.

But the ref doesn't generate a link!

My docstrings are generated with autosummary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the angle brackets with text override in the ref, or leave them out. In other words, remove the angle brackets (and what's inside), unless you are going to override the text.

The error message should be better.