# Sphinx cross reference what goes in angle brackets?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I see a lot of examples like

```
:ref:`code <target to code>`
```

in the Sphinx documentation, but I can't find where it defines what `code`  and `<target to code>` mean. Perhaps one of them is an implicit or explicit target and the other is the path to a file??

If someone can give me examples of how to cross reference a title in a specific .rst file?

From [Adding a cross-reference to a subheading or anchor in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another-page) I know how to use the `:any` role, but not how to do a `:ref:` to a specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax):

> Cross-references are generated by many semantic interpreted text roles. Basically, you only need to write
>
> ```
> :role:`target`
> ```
>
> and a link will be created to the item named *target* of the type indicated by *role*. The link’s text will be the same as *target*.
>
> There are some additional facilities, however, that make cross-referencing roles more versatile:
>
> - You may supply an explicit title and reference target, like in reST direct hyperlinks:
>
>   ```
>   :role:`title <target>`
>   ```
>
>   will refer to *target*, but the link text will be *title*.

Note that sometimes *title* is also called *label*, depending on context.