# How to activate auto header generation in jupyter-book?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, jupyterbook, myst

In my jupyter-book, I want to [reference a section header](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/references.html#reference-with-markdown-link-syntax) in the same document using the syntax below:

```
I want to refer to [section](intro.md#how-to-learn-python]
```

where `intro.md` is your current markdown file, and `how-to-learn-python` is a section inside this document.

I read that [MyST-Parser has Auto-generated header anchors](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#syntax-header-anchors) which allow me to do so using the above method. But after I placed my configuration into `_config.yml`:

```
parse:
  myst_heading_anchors: 3
```

It still did not work. Currently, the jupyter-book tutorial requires me to create a tag manually for each section header, which consumes a lot of time.

Other references:

- [Adding a cross-reference to a subheading or anchor in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394347/adding-a-cross-reference-to-a-subheading-or-anchor-in-another-page)
- https://daobook.github.io/MyST-Parser/sphinx/use.html#automatically-create-targets-for-section-headers
- https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#syntax-header-anchors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the reason to be that the jupyter-book config module , which generates the Sphinx configuration, does not include `myst_heading_anchors`.

<s>So far, I've only managed to enable the feature by manually adding the entry to `get_default_sphinx_config` in jupyter-book's `config.py`. This is obviously not a clean or permanent solution, but at least a first step towards a solution. A better solution would be to somehow communicate the directive via the `_config.yml` config file.</s>

You can add the configuration directive to the generated config by adding

```
sphinx:
  config:
    myst_heading_anchors: 3
```

to your `_config.yml`.