# reStructuredText sphinx link to another document's anchor

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Let's assume two reStructuredText files in same Sphinx project. Files are located on the same directory.
One of them -`foo.rst` contains section `bar`, like:

```
bar
===
some items...
```

How do I link to `bar` anchor in another *.rst document?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4385315/407651

Comment: Thanks for the link - it gave me an idea where I did wrong. Testing and will update.

Comment: Even more answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15394347/407651

Comment: This question shall be closed - 
answers contained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/15394347/407651. Briefly - add extension `autosectionlabel`, but section names couldn't be doubled then and sphinx will raise warnings when compiling. The second (workaround) is to add `.. _foo:` in document which have to be linked.