# How to Reference a Sub-Heading Inside a Note in rST

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a file in the folder `/pages/architecture-deployment-guide.rst` this file has two subheadings:

`View MAC Addresses of Each Container Interface`

`==============================================`

`View MAC Addresses of Each Bridge Interface`

`===========================================`

I want to reference these subheadings in another file path named `/pages/view-packet-captures.rst`

I want it to be inside a note.

```
..  Note::

   Go to, "View Mac Addresses of Each Bridge Interface" and "View Mac Addresses of Each Container Interface" to confirm the MAC addresses of each device when analyzing the packet capture.
```

How do I go about it? I can't see resources online

Comment: How about the `:ref:` role? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4385315/407651

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was initially trying that `:ref:` but the resource I saw was asking that I specify an extension `sphinx.ext.autoselectionLabel`. I'm glad it's sorted out now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. Thanks to @mzjn for the tip.

Highlight the sub-section.

```
.. _view_mac_address_of_each_bridge_interface:

View MAC Addresses of Each Bridge Interface

===========================================


.. _view_mac_address_of_each_container_interface:

View MAC Addresses of Each Bridge Interface

===========================================
```

Next, reference it in the notes.

```
..  Note::
   Go to, :ref:`view_mac_address_of_each_bridge_interface` and :ref:`view_mac_address_of_each_container_interface` to confirm the MAC addresses of each device when analyzing the packet capture.
```